# Are women obligated to recite hallel on certain holidays

Tags: halacha, women, hallel, orach-chaim, time-bound

According to Halacha, a woman is exempt from certain time bound mitzvot. My question is, are women obligated to recite Hallel on certain Jewish holidays, or since it is time bound to those days are they exempt?

Comment: There's three relevant times which may have different rulings: Yom Tov, Chanukah, Seder night.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Beur Halachah 422:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Biur_Halacha.422.2.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he):

> ומבואר עוד בש"ס סוכה ל"ח ובפוסקים דנשים פטורות מהלל ומשום דהיא מצוה שהזמן גרמא [חוץ מהלל דלילי פסחים דחייבות משום שאף הן היו באתו הנס כ"כ תוס' שם]
>
> It is clear from the Gemara, Sukkah 38a, and Poskim that women are exempt from Hallel, because it is a timebound mitzvah (with the exception of Hallel on Pesach night, in which they are obligated since they were also part of that miracle, as stated in Tosafos there).

Comment: Not everyone agrees about Chanukah, when also אף הן היו באותו הנס

Answer (score 3):

Chanukah is a point of contention.

A few Acharonim dispute the general consensus that they don't say Hallel as they were also included in the miracle. (See similarly about Pesach, [Pesachim 38a, Tosafos s.v. Mi](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Sukkah.38a.8.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

For example, Rav Wosner ([Shevet HaLevi 1:205](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1411&st=&pgnum=264&hilite=)) questions if women are obligated in Hallel as in lighting. He writes accordingly that women do in fact have an obligation in Hallel on Chanukah.

Also, using the Tosafos as springboard, is Rav [Refoel Shapiro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refael_Shapiro) - who in his [Toras Refoel 75](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1490&st=&pgnum=269&hilite=) says similarly:

> וכן דחנוכה נמי חייבות שהרי מטעם נס הוא.
>
> And similarly with Chanukah also they are obligated (in Hallel) because of this reason of the miracle (that they also experienced.)

Comment: I imagine for those who say you have to say Hallel for modern Israeli miracles it would be the same as Chanukah